# I have a window that has been set to open in 'window.top' - need to open in a new window

Tags: javascript, window

Need to open final destination URL in a new window - not in "window.top".  What do I need to change below? (someone else wrote this and is inaccessible).

```
<script>
if (window.self === window.top) {
    var finalDest = 'https://www.amazon.com',
        iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
        iframeLoaded = 0;

    [].forEach.call(iframes, function(item) {
        item.onload = function() {
            loadFrames();
        }
    })
}
function loadFrames() {
    iframeLoaded++;

    if (iframeLoaded === iframes.length) {
        location.href = finalDest;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to open a new window? a search for "javascript open new window" would yield `window.open()`

Comment: I need it done in the context of this script.